# Why bean definitions is stored in concurrent hashmap?

Tags: java, spring, ioc-container

In the class [`DefaultListableBeanFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultListableBeanFactory.html) there is

```
private final Map<String, BeanDefinition> beanDefinitionMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(256);
```

where bean definitions are stored. I'm new to Spring and I don't understand why IoC container need concurrency for the hashmap. As far as I understand, we just read bean definitions from XML file and store them in hashmap.

Why don't we use regular `HashMap` for the purpose?

Comment: Because `HashMap` is not threadsafe? (Also, beans can be defined using annotations instead of xml, and, AFAIK, this is the more common way nowadays)

Comment: By default all beans in spring are Singleton. i.e. there should be only one instance of the bean. 

Now. lets say you have declared the same bean at two different places. During spring startup, it does component scan and puts all the beans into this map. 
So if two threads scans the two beans you created, there is a chance that both get inserted. If that happens then there are two instance of the same bean. I believe to avoid these situations, thread safe map is used

Comment: I think it has less to do with singleton. It's more about bean registration code which will be creating beans in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the bean creation could happen in parallel. The Map is hence going to be critical data. And hence, if there is any update to same key it's done in serial mode and not parallel.

That's why `ConcurrentHashMap` is used. Now another question who would be registering the beans in parallel. So, it could be any user of `DefaultListableBeanFactory`. So to make all the operations on `beanDefinitionMap` thread safe `ConcurrentHashMap` has been used.

Let's understand it by example:-

```
 private final DefaultListableBeanFactory factory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) applicationContext
        .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();

private void registerBean(String beanName, String scope) throws IOException {

    GenericBeanDefinition genericBeanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
    genericBeanDefinition.setBeanClassName("org.jibeframework.core.util.ViewComponentFactory");
    genericBeanDefinition.setScope(scope);
    genericBeanDefinition.setAutowireMode(GenericBeanDefinition.AUTOWIRE_NO);
    genericBeanDefinition.setDependencyCheck(AbstractBeanDefinition.DEPENDENCY_CHECK_NONE);
    BeanDefinitionHolder holder = new BeanDefinitionHolder(genericBeanDefinition, beanName, new String[] {});
    BeanDefinitionReaderUtils.registerBeanDefinition(holder, factory);

}
```

Now `if this code is called inside a Thread` could lead to data inconsistency, race conditions etc. That's why all methods inside `DefaultListableBeanFactory` also acquire different locks(`together with using ConcurrentHashMap`) while performing operations like `registerBeanDefinition`.

Take a look at DefaultListableBeanFactory#registerBeanDefinition to get more clarity. A ref link [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultListableBeanFactory.html#registerBeanDefinition-java.lang.String-org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition-).